# Bash - how can I check if I'm under Graphic Session?

Tags: linux, bash, tty, xorg

I want know how I can check in any Linux distro if I am inside an "Xorg / XFree86 / XSystem / Mir / Wayland" session.

and if yes im under Xsession run commands
and if not run commands in cli mode

I tried the following:

```
xtty=`w -hs | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u | sed 's/^[tty \t]*//' | sed -n '$p'` && echo "tty X(org/Free86/System) = $xtty"
```

But this just for knowing which tty I'm in.

In some distros, the Graphics Modes are in tty1, tty5, tty6, or tty7.
But, I want to know if I'm logged into that tty, and if I'm in a graphical session.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure on X and wayland (just guessing on MIR based on the source code):

```
[ "$DISPLAY" ] || [ "$WAYLAND_DISPLAY" ] || [ "$MIR_SOCKET" ] && echo graphical environment
```